# What's the fastest way to read a .docx file line-by-line in c# using openxml

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

I need to read this Word (.DOC and .DOCX) file line by line using OpenXML.

[image]

In this code I have set an `regexp` is to check if a line starts with a whitespace, a letter, the bullet character or the - character or number

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {

        string file = @"C:\Users\Downloads\qst.docx";

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
        {
            Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            string contents = "";

            var reg = new Regex(@"^[\s\p{L}\d\•\-\►]");

            foreach (Paragraph co in
                        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(somethingElse =>
                        reg.IsMatch(somethingElse.InnerText)))
            {
                if (co.ParagraphProperties != null || co.ParagraphProperties.NumberingProperties != null)
                {
                    contents += co.InnerText + "<br />";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do other checking.
                }
            }

            Response.Write(contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code the return in browser is wrong, because the bulleted and numbered lists of the word file are not displayed...

```
Section 1

- Para 1.1
Content 1.1
test 2
test 3

•Gaio Giulio Cesare
•Quinto Orazio Flacco
•Marco Porcio Catone


Section 2

- Para 2.1
Content 2.1
test 4
test 5

- Gaio Giulio Cesare
- Quinto Orazio Flacco
- Marco Porcio Catone

► Marco Porcio Catone
► Quinto Orazio Flacco
► Gaio Giulio Cesare
```

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/340644/what39s-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-docx-file-line-b.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Take a look at [Wordprocessing Numbering, Levels & Lists](http://officeopenxml.com/WPnumbering.php). As you will see lists in OpenXML do not contain the actual bullet symbol. They contain a separate `<w:abstractNum>` definition which the paragraph element references.

Comment: Why request the fastest way? Are there any performance requirements you need to meet?

Comment: @Kwiksilver thanks fo reply. it means to modify in this way? Not working...
`var reg = new Regex(@"^[\s\p{L}\d\•\-\►\<w:abstractNum>]");`

Comment: @Kwiksilver data processing should be fast

Comment: Both [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/index.html) .docx to text and MSWords save as text function may not even meet your requirements. Word just saves all bullets as an * regardless weather the bullet is a triangle square or otherwise. Automatic numbering like i, ii, iii, iv, v and 1 2 3 4 and a b c d e. do save as a list. Is this functionality good enough?

Comment: @Kwiksilver Using Pandoc with Visual studio 2019?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230641/discussion-between-kwiksilver-and-edward-sheriff-curtis).